# Why do some attributes require different modification methods than others with Set-Aduser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Typically I use the "set-aduser -replace" option for updating attributes in Active Directory, but I am finding that some attributes require a different syntax to modify them and I was just wondering why.  A good example of this are the two attributes below, Office and physicalDeliveryName, same cmdlet to modify, but different syntax.  Are all attributes not created equally?

```
$users = gc -Path C:\0NIX\03SCRIPTS\TMP\jkirb\allen.txt            

foreach ($user in $users) {            
    Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties * | Select samaccountname, Office, physicalDeliveryOfficeName            
    Set-ADuser $user -Office "Allen"
    Set-ADuser $user -replace @{physicalDeliveryOfficeName="Allen"}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence of the [Detailed Description](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx#sectionSection2) of the help for `Set-ADUser` explains this:

> The Set-ADUser cmdlet modifies the properties of an Active Directory user. You can modify commonly used property values by using the cmdlet parameters. Property values that are not associated with cmdlet parameters can be modified by using the Add, Replace, Clear and Remove parameters.

So it appears to be nothing more than Microsoft having provided convenience arguments for the common properties. I imagine you can just always use the longer syntax as well (even for the common properties) to make for uniform code (and easier function-wrapping, etc.).